# What depth should water be filled to in a cylinder flask to make it the most stable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, gravity

As said in title, a cylinder flask with a mass of 100g and radius of 3 has a center of balence 10cm above the base. Assuming negligible wall thickness, to what depth should water be added to this flask to make it the most stable.

The question doesn't give any other information and I'm at a loss of how to approach this question. Any help or tips in the right direction would be great

Comment: Think of tipping the cylinder over. The greatest angle before the cylinder (plus water) would tip would be the most stable.

Comment: You could try experimenting with a similar bottle, seriously. Might give you a rough idea of the correct level and it could be easier to test and learn from that. Homework questions may well be closed unless you follow the guidelines, best of luck with it anyway.

Comment: "Radius of 3", what? Potatoes? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Goutham is quite correct in some ways but overlooks something. Look at the diagram below:

[image: Cylinder and water.]

We known the centre of gravity (COG) of the empty cylinder is $z_1=10\:\mathrm{cm}$ and the mass of the empty cylinder is $100\:\mathrm{g}$.

If we fill the cylinder up with water to height $2z_2$ then the COG of the water is $z_2$ and the mass of water is (assuming the radius is $3\:\mathrm{cm}$ and the density of water is $1\:\mathrm{g/cm^3}$):

$$m_2=18\pi z_2.$$

The overall COG $z$ of the cylinder plus water can then be calculated as:

$$z=\frac{1000+18\pi z_2^2}{10+18\pi z_2}.$$

As Goutham points out, stability is highest for lowest $z$ and $z_{min}$ can be found for:

$$\frac{dz}{dz_2}=0.$$

Unfortunately that really only holds when the added mass is a non-flowing material. For a liquid, the moment you tilt the cylinder $z_2$ starts moving in the same direction, as well as downward.

So Goutham's approach is at best approximate. An accurate prediction would have to take into account the effect of tilt on $z_2$ and thus also $z$. For tall, thin cylinders the effect of tilt on $z$ is of course smaller than for stubby, wide ones.

Answer (score 1):

The flask become most stable when its centre of gravity is at the smallest height. If you start pouring water, you will notice that the effective centre of gravity gets down to a lower postion. As you keep on filling, it would be at the lowest height for some level of water and rises again, afterwards. You will have to find that point of minimum height. Just frame an equation relating height of water and height of resultant centre of gravity, find the derivative and equate to zero

Comment: I wonder, though, if it's simply a matter of the location of the center of gravity. Seems like another factor to consider is the total weight of the cylinder. For example, isn't it conceivable that the most stable cylinder actually has a water level which is a bit higher than that which corresponds to the lowest center of gravity, because by adding a little extra water the small incremental rise in the center of gravity is more than offset by the incremental increase in the mass of the cylinder? Maybe the meaning of "most stable" needs to be examined here.

Comment: I think , more stable means that the lesser probablity that cylinder have, to get toppled over. If we tilt the cylinder through a small angle, lower the centre of gravity is, the lesser will the torque due to gravity be.

Comment: Is it right to assume that the point where the level of water matches the center of gravity will result in the lowest possible center of gravity and therefore the most stable cylinder?

Comment: Yes indeed. I just confirmed it by equating that derivative to zero. The level of water that matches the height of resultant height of centre of gravtiy(water +flask) corresponds to maximum cylinder stability