# How far should I fill up a water bottle to make it the most resilient to accidental bumping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, statics

I came across a situation similar to the one in the picture shown below, where you have a water bottle that is being knocked over by accident. Naturally, I wondered how much I would have to fill a bottle with water to make sure it is the most resilient to being knocked over.

[image]

When I googled around I found [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219538/what-depth-should-water-be-filled-to-in-a-cylinder-flask-to-make-it-the-most-sta), but when I asked some engineers, they told me I would also have to take into account the inertia of the water.

Basically, I found two philosophies surrounding this problem:

1. The fuller the bottle, the more mass it has and therefore the more inertia it has
2. The lower the center of mass, the more likely the bottle is to tip back after being knocked over

I started thinking about the physics behind both philosophies, but I find it hard to figure out a way to compare both approaches. Does anyone have any tips to get me on the right track?

Please do let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Try totally empty.

Comment: If you can arrange that the water stays at the bottom and does not move that would help...

Comment: @ChetMiller thank you for the input, however, a bottle that does contain water is a bit heavier than an empty bottle so I have to conclude that does not work.

SolarMike thank you too for the input, I thought so too but that could make a significant difference between the theoretical solution and what happens in reality

Comment: it would help also if you describe where do you push the bottle

Comment: @SartemCacartem Also, can we assume that the impact transfer a fixed amount of momentum from the hand (or let's say it's a projectile for simplicity) to the bottle?

Comment: @KeithMcClary are you making an assumption on behalf of the OP?  perhaps let the OP clarify.

Comment: @SolarMike The OP invited requests for more info. Alternatively, the hand could hit with fixed velocity, for example. I think we need to know that.

Comment: @KeithMcClary then direct your question to the OP, not another commenter...

Comment: @SolarMike The OP is automagically notified, it was just a FYI for the other.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting discussion everyone, I just woke up so now I can give more information.
1. SartemCacartem, since there is uncertainty about where the hand will hit, I suppose a variable H_hand could be useful, but then again it might also be insightful to consider the edge cases: top and bottom of the bottle

2. realistically the only velocity that should matter is the impact velocity (I think), and since the total momentum is always conserved, I suppose it will be a fixed amount if I understand your suggestion correctly?

I seriously underestimated this problem, thanks all!